# Facing an issue while subscribing to fcm with new refresh token

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, angularfire

I am using AngularFireMessaging to handle FCM tokens in an angular app.
The issue is when the user clicks on allow, it creates a token and hit this link to subscribe. https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/connect/subscribe

But now the response is coming as an error. 503.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 503,
    "message": "The service is currently unavailable.",
    "status": "UNAVAILABLE"
  }
}
```

Any idea how to resolve this.

I am using below js libraries in the service worker(firebase-messaging-sw.js) as an import

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here, other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.0/firebase-messaging.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just that FCM blocking multiple requests to register multiple tokens in short interval of time. Not quite clear the time gap. It starts working after 10 hours and so.